# initialize array with constant number does not work

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I get the following error when I use constant `nVar` instead of a number.

**constants.h:**

```
extern const unsigned int nVar;
```

**constants.cpp:**

```
#include "constants.h"
const unsigned int nVar = 5;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "constants.h"
void foo(const double q[nVar])
{
    // ...
}
```

**Compiler:**

array constant is not an integer constant before ']' token

expected ')' before ',' token

expected unqualified-id before 'const'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it happens because compiler should know array's size at compile time, but in your example value of nVar will be known only at linking time due to extern

Comment: Correct. Move the assignment (=5) part to the header file and it will compile fine - in that case the compiler knows the size of that array.

Comment: @parry: Firstly, `= 5` is not assignment, it is initialization. Secondly, simply moving `= 5` to the header file will immediately trigger ODR violations (typically reported as "multiple definition" linker errors). In order to be able to specify `= 5` in the header file the object has to be given internal linkage, i.e. `extern` has to be removed.

Comment: AndreyT Pedantry was never my interest :) It is besides the point too which was that the compiler should know the size of the array when it encounters it. I am sure we can trust OP to put the initialization and assignments in the right place - I wasn't suggesting it as a best practice, just illustrating that it would make the size visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not "initializing" the array with a constant in our example. You are specifying the size of the array. Note that in the given example the array size will be ignored anyway. Your declaration

```
void foo(const double q[nVar])
```

is actually equivalent to

```
void foo(const double q[])
```

and to

```
void foo(const double *q)
```

Secondly, in order for integral constant to be usable in a constant expression it has to be declared *with an initializer*. In your `main.cpp` your constant is declared without an initializer, which means that it can't form constant expressions and can't be used in array declarators.

Unless you really need a const object with external linkage, the proper way to declare your constant would be

```
const unsigned int nVar = 5;
```

right in the header file. Note: no `extern` and the initializer is specified right in the header file. The definition in `constants.cpp` has to be removed in that case. Technically, this will create an independent `nVar` object with internal linkage in each translation unit, but it won't normally occupy any memory unless used as an lvalue.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me, this sounds like the rules for a `static const` member variable, but that doesn't apply to `const` global variables does it?  And even `static const` need defining in a translation unit if you want to use it as an lvalue.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I'm not sure what you are trying to say and what it has to do with member variables. Namespace-scope variable declaration with an initializer is always a *definition*, meaning that it is already defined. No need to define anything in a translation unit. As for whether it will occupy memory if used only in constant expressions - it is largely a quality-of-implementation issue.

Comment: I always thought this would result in ODR violations unless it was marked as `extern`.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: In C++ (as opposed to C) namespace-scope `const` objects have internal linkage by default, i.e. plain `const` is equivalent to `static const`. For that reason it does not produce ODR violations.

Comment: oh, never knew that.  Makes sense I guess.