# Writing a C++ function to operate on arrays declared externally

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, extern, linkage

I am trying to write a set of C++ functions (`a.h`, `a.cpp`) that implement various operations on arrays. The actual arrays will be defined in other files (`b.h`, `b.cpp`, `c.h`, `c.cpp`, etc.).

My goal is that any project can `#include "a.h"` and run these functions on arrays defined in that project. I don't want to have to include anything in `a.h` itself, because I want any future project to be able to use `a.h` without rewriting it. But, I can't figure out how to use `extern` to do this.

Here's a toy example of what I have so far. `a` implements a function `f`, to be used on an as-yet unspecified array.

a.h

```
// this is not right, but I'm not sure what to do instead
extern const int ARRAY_LEN;
extern int array[ARRAY_LEN]; // error occurs here

void f();
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

// Do something with every element of "array"
void f() {
  for(int i=0; i < ARRAY_LEN; i++) {
    array[i];
  }
}
```

Now, project `b` defines the array and wants to use the function `f` on it.

b.h

```
const int ARRAY_LEN = 3;
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int array[ARRAY_LEN] = {3, 4, 5};

// Some functions here will use f() from a.cpp
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
In file included from b.cpp:1:0:
a.h:2:27: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

I read these other questions which are related:

- [initialize array with constant number does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866267/initialize-array-with-constant-number-does-not-work)
- ["array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token" when using multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749238/array-bound-is-not-an-integer-constant-before-token-when-using-multiple-fi)
- [Why does "extern const int n;" not work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894698/why-does-extern-const-int-n-not-work-as-expected)

... but I can't see how to apply the solutions to my case. The problem is that usually people end up `#include`-ing the files that define the array, and I want to do it the other way around: define the array in a new project, and `#include` the shared set of functions to operate on that array.

---

Edit 1: If I replace the declaration of `array` in `a.h` with the following, as suggested by @id256:

```
extern int array[];
```

Then I get a different error:

```
multiple definition of `ARRAY_LEN'
```

---

Edit 2: I also tried the answer from:

[Why does "extern const int n;" not work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894698/why-does-extern-const-int-n-not-work-as-expected?lq=1)

Basically, I added "extern const int ARRAY_LEN" to `b.h` in order to "force external linkage". So now:

b.h

```
extern const int ARRAY_LEN;
const int ARRAY_LEN = 3;
```

.. and all other files are the same as originally. But I get the same original error:

```
a.h:2:27: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token
```

Comment: So what's the problem with declaring `extern int array[]`?

Comment: This should be done by passing the arrays as parameter to the functions; not by using global variables.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and pass arrays or vectors by reference parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring an array as `extern`, you don't need to specify the size (for a multi-dimensional array, you still need all but the first dimension). Just use:

```
extern int array[];
```

Alternatively, include b.h in a.h (before declaring the array) so that the definition of `ARRAY_LEN` is visible when you declare the array.

Comment: Hm, I think my "Edit 1" addresses your first suggestion, and it leads to a different error. As for your second suggestion, I agree this would work, but the main reason I'm asking this question is because I don't want to include b.h in a.h, or for a.h to have to know anything about b.h.

Comment: @cxrodgers remove the declaration of ARRAY_LEN from a.h; it doesn't match the definition of ARRAY_LEN in b.h, and you're not allowed to have two mis-matching declarations/definitions of the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I tried this. I also had to add `extern const int ARRAY_LEN` to a.cpp and now it works. I edited your answer to include this line and to show the full working code. Thanks!